# Function to return all the data within a table

Tags: typescript, office-scripts

The following function returns the data of Table1 excluding the headers:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let ws = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
    return ws.getTable("Table1").getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getValues();
}
```

How do I get it to return ALL the data, including the headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
  let ws = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
  return ws.getTable("Table1").getRange().getValues();
}
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [getRange()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.table?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&view=office-scripts#excelscript-excelscript-table-getrange-member(1))